# Concatenating two strings : C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider Below code for concatenating two `char arrays` with a `delimiter`:

```
void addStrings(char* str1,char* str2,char del)
{
//str1=str1+str2
int len1=strlen(str1);
int len2=strlen(str2);
int i=0;
//char* temp=(char*) malloc((len1+1)*sizeof(char));
//strcpy(temp,str1);
str1=(char*) realloc(str1,(len1+len2+1)*sizeof(char));
printf("Here--%d\n",strlen(str1));
*(str1+len1)=del; //adding delimiter
for(i=0;i<=len2;i++)
    *(str1+len1+i+1)=*(str2+i);
printf("Concatenated String: %s\n",str1);
i=0;
    while( *(str1+i) != '\0')
    {
            printf("~~%d:%c\n",i,*(str1+i));
        i++;
    }

}
```

When running this function with `addStrings("A","test",'@');`; The code crashes as `realloc` below is `gdb output`

```
Breakpoint 3, addStrings (str1=0x40212f <_data_start__+303> "A", str2=0x40212a <_data_start__+298> "test",
    del=64 '@') at string.c:34
34      int len1=strlen(str1);
(gdb) s
35      int len2=strlen(str2);
(gdb) s
36      int i=0;
(gdb) s
39      str1=(char*) realloc(str1,(len1+len2+1)*sizeof(char));
(gdb)

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x004012f2 in addStrings (str1=0xc0 <Address 0xc0 out of bounds>,
    str2=0xea60 <Address 0xea60 out of bounds>, del=0 '\000') at string.c:39
39      str1=(char*) realloc(str1,(len1+len2+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Not able to figure out why it is crashing? Is it because I am passing `str1` as `auto` variable rather than creating it on `heap`?

If this is the case ? How do I modify my code to accept `auto` as well as `heap` variables?

Comment: You're pointers passed in are by-value. You will realloc, but once you return from your function the realloc address return value is gone, the original is left on the caller side. Worse, this will hide as a non-issue until an actual resize beyond the minimum suballocator partition length is reached and the return result of realloc is different than the passed in value. And your sample call is nonsense, as you're passing an address ("A") that wasn't even originally dynamically allocated in the first place, so realloc is useless.

Comment: @BlueMoon `addStrings("A","test",'@');`

Comment: Also you use the original variable `str1` for the return value of `realloc`. If `realloc` fails you will loose the original pointer and the memory is lost. Use a temporary pointer for the return value to check realloc success

Comment: @GauravK Yes. I see that you updated the question.

Comment: is this for an exercise? any reason to not use strcat?

Comment: @WhozCraig It works well if I call the function as `addStrings(temp,"test",'@');` where `temp` I have initialized with `malloc`. But suppose I write `char* name="Hello";` and then call `addStrings(name,"test",'@');` it crashes

Comment: @Ben Yes .. just trying to write my own function

Comment: @GauravK it won't "work" as soon as a true-reallocation happens and the result of `realloc()` is different than the passed in pointer value. When that happens the original pointer value on the caller-side is indeterminate and any dereference will invoke UB. Adding salt into the wound, it also leaks memory when that happens. You need to pass your "target" pointer *by address* . As I said, its UB hiding in plain site waiting for that true-realloc to happen, then boom.

Comment: @WhozCraig So I need to take care of two things:
1) `str1` must be dynamically initialized
2) For `realloc` if it actually reallocates i.e. the `pointer` returned by `realloc` is different from my `str1` it will crash.....
If I understood correctly.....

Comment: Your computation is incorrect - it should be len1+len2+2.  You need space for str1, delimiter, str2 and terminator.

Comment: You can't realloc a string literal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass your target string pointer by address, and it *must* hold either the address of a previously allocate string, or NULL (if coded correctly). The size allocation must be both lengths + 2 (one for the deli separator, one for the terminator). The result can look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void addStrings(char** str1, const char* str2,char del)
{
    size_t len1 = *str1 ? strlen(*str1) : 0;
    size_t len2 = str2 ? strlen(str2) : 0;
    char *res = realloc(*str1, len1 + len2 + 2);
    if (res)
    {
        res[len1] = del;
        memcpy(res + len1 + 1, str2, len2);
        res[len1 + 1 + len2] = 0;
        *str1 = res;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *p = NULL;
    const char test[] = "test";
    int i=0;

    // prove it works with no input whatsoever
    addStrings(&p, NULL, 'X');
    printf("p = %p, %s\n", p, p);

    // loop on some input for awhile
    for (;i<10;++i)
    {
        addStrings(&p, test, '@');
        printf("p = %p, %s\n", p, p);
    }
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
p = 0x128610, X
p = 0x128610, X@test
p = 0x128610, X@test@test
p = 0x128620, X@test@test@test
p = 0x128620, X@test@test@test@test
p = 0x128620, X@test@test@test@test@test
p = 0x128620, X@test@test@test@test@test@test
p = 0x128640, X@test@test@test@test@test@test@test
p = 0x128640, X@test@test@test@test@test@test@test@test
p = 0x128640, X@test@test@test@test@test@test@test@test@test
p = 0x128670, X@test@test@test@test@test@test@test@test@test@test
```

<sub>Compiled with: 
     Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
     Target: i386-apple-darwin13.2.0
     Thread model: posix</sub>

Note the change in resulting address on *some* of the passes. I leave the checking for valid parameter input as an exercise for you.